# Increment and Decrement value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, object

I have a minor problem am trying to have a set of buttons that would increment and decrement an input value by 1 when triggered, at the moment the actual value increases and decreases fine. There are several links provided before the actual modal shows up on the page but the main problem is, once I perform the increment process and reopen the modal I expect to have an initial value on the modal input element which is '1' but unfortunately once I try to increment the input value it tends to increment more that 1 and jump all the way to 3.

**Here the JS script:**

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    var o = {
        input: $('#item-quantity'), // Input element on modal
        add: function (x) {
            this.i = this.i + x;
        }
    };

    // Execute once the modal show is triggered
    $('#addItem').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        o.i = 1;
        o.input.val(o.i);
    });

    // Execute once the modal fully loads
    $('#addItem').on("shown.bs.modal", function (e) {

        // Increment button on click
        $('.more-item').on('click', function () {
            o.add(1);
            o.input.val(o.i);
        });

        // Decrement button on click
        $('.sub-item').on('click', function () {

            if (o.i != 1) {
                o.i -= 1;
            }
            o.input.val(o.i);
        });

        // Modal close button on click
        $('.close').on('click', function () {
            o.input.val(0);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I would put some log statements within these functions and see how many times they are being called

Comment: `$('.more-item').on('click', function () {});` you are compounding events, meaning you are adding more than one event onto each .more-item elements.

Comment: Patrick is on the right track, but what I think is going on, is that each time your modal shows, you are binding an additional event, without unbinding the previous one. So your click event handler fires twice. I would either move those events out of on('shown.bs.modal'), or i would add an off() call for each one in the close event.

Comment: There's also `stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Comment: @agmcleod Well your details served me better thanks.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks i understood now i was actually triggering more events onto the same element.

Comment: @SharkesMonken Good to know.  I've never worked with mobile devices.